# How to convert carriage returns into actual line breaks

Tags: c#, text, replace, line-breaks

I have a text file that I downloaded from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sujithps/Dictionary/master/Oxford%20English%20Dictionary.txt) (it's just the English dictionary) which displays fine in a browser, but when I open it in Notepad it doesn't recognize the line breaks. I thought a simple C# application could detect the flavor of carriage returns they use and turn them into actual line breaks and spit out a more nicely formatted txt file but I've failed with techniques like `String.Replace("\r", "\n");` that I thought would be easy tricks. How are these carriage returns encoded and how can I reformat the file to make it readable in something like Notepad? C# is preferred because that's what I'm used to, but if it's easier in some other method I'll be happy to consider alternatives.

Comment: If you just need to be able to view it, download notepad++ to view it. It's using LF (line feed) to separate each line.

Comment: if you open it in wordpad and save the file back you won't even need to install anything.

Comment: Open in pretty much any editor (i.e. VS) and save with line endings of your choice. If you have coding question make sure to show [MCVE] of what you've tried and how it did not work.

Comment: After posting I noticed it showed up fine in notepad++ but I actually ultimately need to manipulate it in a C# app so I want to make sure I've got the encoding right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this in c# all you need to do is this...

```
File.WriteAllLines("outfile.txt", File.ReadAllLines("infile.txt"));
```

... If you want slightly more complex yet faster and less memory do it this way ...

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("infile.txt"))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("outfile.txt"))
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
```

... if you really want to overkill it as an excuse to use extension methods and LINQ then do this ...

```
//Sample use
//"infile.txt".ReadFileAsLines()
//            .WriteAsLinesTo("outfile.txt");
public static class ToolKit
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFileAsLines(this string infile)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(infile))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("infile");
        if (!File.Exists(infile))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found", infile);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(infile))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void WriteAsLinesTo(this IEnumerable<string> lines, string outfile)
    {
        if (lines == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lines");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outfile))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("outfile");

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outfile))
            foreach (var line in lines)
                writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does that do that would solve the problem?

Comment: The `ReadAllLines` will parse the file and split just as `TextReader` (ie. on `\n` or `\r\n`) and  then `WriteAllLines` will put the file back together with the system default `NewLine` which for windows is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad is the only Windows text editor I know, which doesn't recognize the Unix-style newlines `\n`, and requires Windows-style newlines `\r\n` to properly format the text. If you convert `\n` to `\r\n`, it will be displayed as intended. Also, any other (modern) text editor should display the text properly as-is.

Comment: Ah that's an interesting piece of information. I guess that begs the further question, will something like `StreamReader` interpret `\r` as a newline?

Comment: See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx): 

`A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").`

So yep, it will interpret `\r` correctly.